# Loading SVG group object into an existing SVG with jQuery not working Safari

Tags: jquery, svg, safari

I have an SVG element already loaded on the page. What I want to do (and works in Chrome and Firefox) is load an additional g object inside the SVG via jQuery.

```
<svg>
    <g id="target"></g>
</svg>
```

Using the following jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').on('click', function (e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#target').load('element.svg');
    });
});
```

Where element.svg contains:

```
<g>
   <path fill="#FF0000" d="M116.6,47.3c0,0-3.6,1... />
</g>
```

Clicking the button works as expected in Chrome and Firefox changing the markup to:

```
<svg>
    <g id="target">
        <g>
            <path fill="#FF0000" d="M116.6,47.3c0,0-3.6,1... />
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

But doesn't work in Safari leaving the node empty. How can I get the same results in Safari?

Comment: If you want the same result in Safari, stop using jquery. load creates elements in the wrong namespace in Safari, you'd need to create them via the DOM directly.